# global variable class saving

Tags: android, variables, store, global

i 'am using :

```
public class GlobalVariables extends Application{
...
}
```

to create some global variables. Is there a simple way to save them all without naming them one by one. A kind of serialization!
The goal is to save those variables that are the state of the app when this one is paused or stopped and reload them on a resume.

Thanks.

Comment: make them static maybe?

Comment: If you're making an Android app, why not use `sharedPreferences`?

Comment: But shared preference i should save them one by one. That's not what i want...

Answer (score 0):

You should not worry about it, your Application "GlobalVariables" class will not mangle your strong references saved on them on pause and on stop.

If your application get completly obliterated from memory, they will get mangled... But the system will call onCreate() on it again when the user opens your app.

Comment: Ok nice. I shouldn't have ben so recise in my question lol. The goal of the app is mainly to learn basics of android (and java) programming. So i am still searcing for a way to do what i want. If it's possible. Thank you for the answer by the way...